# Registering Dingo route

Tags: php, laravel, dingo-api

I'm bit confused. Where do I register the router? Inside `routes/api.php`? Or elsewhere?

> To avoid complications with your main application routes this package utilizes its own router. As such we must first get an instance of the API router to create our endpoints.

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
```

Source: [Dingo documentation](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Creating-API-Endpoints)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some elaboration `routes/api.php` is the right place